# Possible errors in a proof concerned with irreflexivity and asymmetry

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that asymmetric relation R would also be irreflexive. My proof is as follows:

Suppose R is not irreflexive. Then a is related to a by R for some a. Then either a is not related to a by R, or, a is related to a by R. The above gives us that a related to a by R implies a related to a by R. But this means that R cannot be asymmetric. Thus if R is asymmetric then R is reflexive.

My problem is with the part: either ~aRa or aRa which is equivalent to aRa implies aRa. This, as I understand, always, regardless of what a is or what R is, holds. Now, if this be so, then no relation can ever be asymmetric. Also, my proof can be tweaked to start with 'Suppose R is irreflexive' to get that if R is asymmetric, R is non-irreflexive.

Where am I going wrong? I'm confused.

(I'm a self-learner, so please be patient.)

Comment: Why does $aRa\to aRa$ mean that $R$ cannot be asymmetric? Asymmetry means that $aRa\to\neg aRa$, which implies $\neg aRa$, which is irreflexivity. The implication $aRa\to aRa$ still holds: it is the "false implies false" case of material implication. It is, as they say, vacuously true.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.